# Realtek sound card, Acer Veriton, Windows 7 - microphone and line inoputs do'nt work

Tags: sound-card

I can record sound from Stereo Mix source but normal level input from Microphone and Line In jacks is so low (and clipped) to be unusable. Is my sound card faulty?

Comment: Problem solved. I had a faulty cable!

Comment: You should add that as an answer below then and self-accept after 2 days so that this question is closed.